# Tridion deployer configuration using the broker database in loadbalanced scenario

Tags: tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I'm currently upgrading an application to Tridion 2011.

We have two loadbalanced webservers and a single database server hosting the broker database. All content is stored in the broker database and all pages are deployed locally on the webserver (the Tridion deployer is installed on the webservers).

Because the broker will write the content and metadata to a shared database, we'll get errors when we deploy to both webservers, as they will both try to store the content. There's a couple of ways to solve this that I know of..

1. Deploy to one webserver that writes the content to the Broker DB and use ftp sync to copy pages and directories to the second webserver.
2. Deploy to one webserver and have the broker write the files to a shared network disk and point both webservers to the shared network disk instead of storing the files locally.
3. Deploy to both webservers and have them work on a seperate database.

I was wondering if Tridion 2011 has more advanced broker features to enable the scenario where I publish to both webservers, but only have one of the webservers actually *write* the content to the database (but both *read*), so I can use 1 broker database instead of 2.

I hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: There is no way we could give you any advice as you have not told us anything about your requirements, servers, content, databases, or in fact anything at all.

Comment: I rewrote the question. Hope it's a bit less ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

Tridion is no clustering server and thus cannot manage your high availability requirements for you. You should see clustering separate from Tridion and then think, how would I solve this without Tridion.

If you have your web/application server setup as high availability with some form of sync in place (for both the filesystem and the broker database), then Tridion can just publish to one of the nodes (which technically can even be behind a load balancer).

If you do not consider clustering software and want a "poor mans" cluster, you should set up both your web/application servers with their own deployer and their own database. Then Tridion can just publish to both nodes and all will be automatically in sync (as long as both nodes are online).